# How do I port my game to the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, web-browsers, processor-speed

I am working on a game and would like to be able to play it on my Raspberry Pi. Right now it's browser based, but I'm not married to that.

Today I ported it over to Pygame, but it's way too slow. I have read that Pyglet is faster, but that it doesn't work on the RPi.

I don't know C++, but I am willing to learn it if that's my only option. I consider this a last resort.

How can I make a game of this complexity play at a reasonable speed on the RPi?

The game: http://engineapp-game.appspot.com/5Ha

I don't think it's relevant, but the physics engine is Box2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know C++, but I am willing to learn it if that's my only option. I consider this a last resort.

Yeah, it's got a steep learning curve.  However, if you are interested in serious game programming, I believe it is the de-facto standard; most consumer retail games, regardless of platform, are written in C++.

Although benchmarks should always be taken with a grain of salt, you'll [notice here](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=python3&lang2=gpp) that python 3 is generally 1-2 orders of magnitude slower than C++.  It also uses considerably more memory.

But of course, C++ requires considerably more source code to do its thing, i.e., it is more labour intensive, which is presumably part of why retail games require a lot of resources to make.  So if you can find a python option that's workable, you might want to stick with it.  On the other hand, if you like coding, are into games, and have too much free time, C++ is very interesting.

Comment: "...if you like coding, are into games, and have too much free time, C++ is very interesting." I do, I am, and I don't.